# Dejar seleccionado el nombre cuando le doy clic; solo he logrado marcarlo cuando paso el cursor sobre él

Tags: html, css

No sé cómo dejar un label seleccionado: solo he podido marcarlo cuando paso el cursor sobre él, pero al darle clic no se queda seleccionado. ¿Cómo se puede hacer? Lo estoy intentando solo con CSS y HTML.

```css
label {
    color: rgb(80, 153, 77);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    /* background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218); */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover{
    background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    opacity: 0.6;
    box-shadow:  0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

```html
<label for="Hipodoge" class="sombreado">Nombre</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con javascript podrías crear un estado, pero si dices solo con CSS+HTML la opción que se me ocurre es que usar un checkbox oculto, enlazarlo con el label mediante la propiedad `for` y si está "checkado" implementar el css.

```css
label {
    color: rgb(80, 153, 77);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    /* background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218); */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover{
    background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    opacity: 0.6;
    box-shadow:  0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 4px blue;
}

.nomostrar{
 display:none;
}

.chkconlabel[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    opacity: 0.6;
    box-shadow:  0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Hipodoge1" class="nomostrar chkconlabel">
<label for="Hipodoge1" class="sombreado">Nombre</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="Hipodoge2" class="nomostrar chkconlabel">
<label for="Hipodoge2" class="sombreado">Nombre</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="Hipodoge3" class="nomostrar chkconlabel">
<label for="Hipodoge3" class="sombreado">Nombre</label>
```